# RecycleView onClickListener - Where to add?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I've been trying to follow the following guide to implement an onClickListener on a RecyclerView

http://blog.lovelyhq.com/creating-lists-with-recyclerview-in-android-part-2/

However, I can't seem to get any context to call setOnClickListener or getPosition.

Here is my code (errors have comments next to them):

```
public class CategoryDataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoryDataAdapter.DataViewHolder> implements View.OnClickListener
{
    private List<CategoryData.Category> dataList;
    private static Context con;

    private ClickListener clickListener;

    public CategoryDataAdapter(Context context, List<CategoryData.Category> list)
    {
        this.dataList = list;
        con = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount()
    {
        return dataList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(DataViewHolder dataViewHolder, int i)
    {
        CategoryData.Category item = dataList.get(i);

        Picasso.with(con).load(item.getImage()).into(dataViewHolder.categoryImage);
        dataViewHolder.categoryText.setText(item.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public DataViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i)
    {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.tile_category, viewGroup, false);
        DataViewHolder dvh = new DataViewHolder(itemView);

        return dvh;
    }

    public static class DataViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        protected ImageView categoryImage;
        protected TextView categoryText;


        public DataViewHolder(View v)
        {
            super(v);

            categoryImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.categoryImage);
            categoryText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.categoryName);

            v.setOnClickListener(this); // here, can't put in 'this'
        }
    }

    public interface ClickListener
    {
        /**
         * Called when the view is clicked.
         *
         * @param v view that is clicked
         * @param position of the clicked item
         * @param isLongClick true if long click, false otherwise
         */

        public void onClick(View v, int position, boolean isLongClick);
    }

    public void setClickListener(ClickListener clickListener)
    {
        this.clickListener = clickListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        clickListener.onClick(v, getPosition(), false); // here, get position
    }
}
```

What can I do to fix this? I only need a click listener for the entire view, not one particular item (already implemented that)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of making `RecyclerView.Adapter` implement `View.OnClickListener`, make `DataViewHolder`  implement that. then also save the rootview at your DataViewHolder variable (like ImageView and TextView) and at `onBindViewHolder` use something like below:

```
dataViewHolder.rootView.setOnClickListener(dataViewHolder);
```

Comment: Accepted. Actually I fixed it myself before reading this but this is exactly what needed to be done. Thanks!

Comment: Good, happy coding :-)

Comment: I have a question though. This onclicklistener is not in my Activity so how do I use it to start another activity?

Comment: Use the context,(pass the activity that holds the recyclerview) then create an intent and call `startActvity();` also note that you should remove `static`  because it leaks the activity.

Comment: Done. Should work. What static part are you referring to though?

Comment: private **static** Context con;

Answer (score 0):

**Add interface for detect click listener in recyclerAdapter**

```
public class DeviceAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Blablah>{
private OnClickItemListener listener;

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ................

    holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(listener != null){
                listener.click(int position)
            }
        }
    });

    .............

    return convertView;
}

public interface OnClickItemListener {
    public void click(int position);
}

public void setOnClickItemListener(OnClickItemListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}
```

}

**And set adapter Listener to your fragment/activity**

```
adapterRecycler.setOnsetOnClickItemListener(new ....{
```

});