# code go to other activity from main activty Adapter

Tags: java, android, adapter

hi this is my Main Activity
please help me
for example when i touch home show Activity home
IDE (Android Studio)
http://flameit.ir/MainActivity.java

and my adapter http://flameit.ir/MyAdapter.java

Comment: simple google will tell you answer just pass activiti Context in your adapter constructor and call your nee activity intent context.startActivity(yourintent)

Comment: can you write code thanks

Comment: check this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30497338/start-activity-from-recycleview-adapter-on-click

Comment: so hard i dont understand :-(

Comment: If you want us to do your work for you at least tell us how much you are paying.

Comment: @Yaser.f it is almost offensive to want us to write code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare new variable in adapter

```
Context mContext;
```

replace your adapter constructor

```
 MyAdapter(String Titles[], int Icons[], String Name, String Email, int Profile) {
        mNavTitles = Titles;
        mIcons = Icons;
        name = Name;
        email = Email;
        profile = Profile;

    }
```

with below

```
 MyAdapter(String Titles[], int Icons[], String Name, String Email, int Profile,Context cntx) {
        mNavTitles = Titles;
        mIcons = Icons;
        name = Name;
        email = Email;
        profile = Profile;
        mContext=cntx;
    }
```

intialize your adapter

```
mAdapter = new MyAdapter(TITLES,ICONS,NAME,EMAIL,PROFILE,MainActivity.this);
```

now where you want to call new activity just put

```
Intent itt=new Intent(mContext,YourNew.class);
mContext.startActivity(itt);
```

if you want to call new activity on recycleview adapter replace below in your adapter

```
public ViewHolder(View itemView, int ViewType) {
            super(itemView);


            if (ViewType == TYPE_ITEM) {
                textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rowText);
                imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rowIcon);
                Holderid = 1;
            } else {


                Name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
                email = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.email);
                profile = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.circleView);
                Holderid = 0;
            }
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent itt=new Intent(mContext,YourNew.class);
        mContext.startActivity(itt);

        }
    });

        }
```

Comment: mAdapter = new MyAdapter(TITLES,ICONS,NAME,EMAIL,PROFILE);  give error main activty

Comment: what you want to say? see in answer 'intialize your adapter'

Comment: oh yes code is ok just where write code Intent itt=new Intent(mContext,YourNew.class);
mContext.startActivity(itt); ? main activity or myadapter

Comment: where you want to call on which event ..in that event you have to put that for example in recyclerview item click

Comment: not work app force close

Comment: where you putting this

Comment: for click listener check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28145143/recycleview-onclicklistener-where-to-add

Comment: how set on click for this???? http://flameit.ir/MainActivity1.java

Comment: @Yaser.f check updated answer

Comment: thanks i change the fragment code